# Is there a utility supporting g++ or clang memory resident compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, server

Apache commons provides a Java API to compile code without loading it from a file. Is there any similar API for C++, either g++ or clang?  I would like to be able to have the compiler loaded in memory and feed it code to compile without having to run it every time, and without having to load the code from a file.

Answer (score 1):

**GCC** accepts input from a pipe:

```
> echo 'int main(){}'|g++ -x c++ -o prog -
```

**note:** you need to specify the language `-x c++` and the end hyphen `-` is important.

Comment: this isn't quite the same thing.  Once the pipe is done, g++ will terminate.  What I am looking for is to keep the compiler in memory and keep piping new files to it